# radio control invisible in Codeception test

Tags: php, codeception

My HTML looks like:

```html
<label class="btn-radio ">
   <input type="radio" value="1" name="pens" class="input_normal">                  
   <span></span>Yes
</label>
...
```

In my codeception test I try to set radio control:

```php
$I->selectOption("//*[@name=pens]/ancestor::label", "1");
```

but it fails with error:

"Couldn't select option "//*[@name='pens' and @value='1']/ancestor::label","1":
ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible".

When I remove the wrapping  tags then it works, but UI is ruined.
Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Did you see this http://automated-testing.info/t/kak-pravilno-vybrat-radio-button-esli-on-pererisovan-na-js/12064 ?

Answer (score 0):

mcklayin gave the correct link to the solution in his comment.
Here is my solution (for others to follow when needed). I had to replace selectOption() with click():

```
$pensionRequestField = "form#loan_application>div.form_fieldset>section>div#step1>div.row>div.col-19-24>fieldset#pension_registry>label#pension_option1";
$I->click(self::$pensionRequestField);
```